# Cancel running Task on Dispose and race condition

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm building a wrapper around `NamedPipeServerStream` and `NamedPipeClientStream`. Currently my `Connect()` method on the `Client` looks like this:

```
    public async Task Connect(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, _connectCancellationTokenSource.Token);

        await _pipe.ConnectAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_pipe.IsConnected)
            {
                _connectCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                _connectCancellationTokenSource = null;
                _pipe.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
                Connection.Set();
                Connected?.BeginInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty, x => ((EventHandler)x.AsyncState).EndInvoke(x), Connected);

                BeginRead();
            }
        }
    }
```

and my `Dispose(bool)` like this:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _connectCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

with the `base.Dispose(bool)` looking like this:

```
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing) return;

        Connection.Reset();
        _pipe.Dispose();
        Connection.Dispose();

        _disposed = true;
    }
```

Basically I can't invoke `Dispose(bool)` while the connection Task is still running and waiting for it to finish is not an option as it might literally run forever.

My workaround was to create a linked `CancellationTokenSource` and use its token as the `CancellationToken` for the `Task`, allowing me to cancel it myself on `Dispose()`.

I then had a race condition where it was entirely possible that the client would connect and pass the `if (_pipe.IsConnected)` only to be disposed of immediately after, causing it to throw on `BeginRead()` (which also uses `_pipe`), hence the `lock` on both `Connect()` and `Dispose()`

However I'm not entirely sure that my approach is really all that sane, and looking for either some validation or ways I could improve this. I'm also concerned I might be putting a bit too much inside the `lock`...

Comment: What happens if you remove this ConfigureAwait(false); ?

Comment: And what if _Dispose_ is called before _Connect_, _pipe_ would be disposed, yet you call _ConnectAsync_?